# python: read a binary file with non ascii name

Tags: python, file, unicode, utf-8

I try to make a script that search in folders for double files and return it In a dictionary like this
{filehash1:[dirfile1,dirfile2],filehash2:[dirfile3]}
(dirfile1 and dirfile2 same file different name/location)

first code:

```
import glob
import hashlib

def getallfolders(dir):
    print dir+"*\\"
    folders = glob.glob(dir+"*\\")
    return folders

def getallfiles(dir):
    folders = glob.glob(dir+"*.*")
    return folders


def filehash(file):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file, 'rb') as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    return hasher.hexdigest()


def double_files(dir):
    mil = {}
    folders = getallfolders(dir)
    for folder in folders:
        mil.update(double_files(folder))
    files = getallfiles(dir)
    for file in files:
        fhash = filehash(file)
        if fhash in mil.keys():
            mil[fhash] = mil[fhash] + [file]
        else:
            mil[fhash] = [file]
    return mil



print double_files("E:\\not organised\\")
```

But if i try to run it, it will crash with error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file
```

It caused because not all the files name in english
so I try to fix it and now the code look like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import glob
import hashlib
import codecs

def getallfolders(dir):
    print dir+"*\\"
    folders = glob.glob(dir+"*\\")
    return folders

def getallfiles(dir):
    folders = glob.glob(dir+"*.*")
    return folders



def filehash(file):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    file = file.decode("utf8")
    with codecs.open(file, "rb", encoding="utf8") as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            buf = buf.encode("ISO-8859-1")
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    return hasher.hexdigest()

def double_files(dir):
    mil = {}
    folders = getallfolders(dir)
    for folder in folders:
        mil.update(double_files(folder))
    files = getallfiles(dir)
    for file in files:
        fhash = filehash(file)
        if fhash in mil.keys():
            mil[fhash] = mil[fhash] + [file]
        else:
            mil[fhash] = [file]
    return mil



print double_files("E:\\not organised\\")
```

I add 
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` 
And change the 
`with open(file, 'rb')` to `with open(file, encoding='utf-8')`
But now i get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte .. in position ..: Tnvalid start byte
```

(the .. mean it not always the same)
It happand in the `buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)` line
I know the file opend but when I try to use the read function it crash with that error.
And i dont know how to solve it...
Please help.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is only for non-ascii **litteral** strings in your code.

Comment: What encoding is the file in? Are you sure it's `utf-8` ?

Comment: it not a specific file it can be a txt jpg and etc

Comment: @Maze88 what about understanding how encoding works instead of programming by accident ? The OP already decode his filenames to unicode (what do you think `file = file.decode("utf8")` is doing ?)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be quite confused about encodings...

- `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is only for non-ascii **litteral** strings in your code.
- `file = file.decode("utf8")` decodes the string `file` (which would be better named `filename`) from utf-8 to unicode. This only works if your filesystem's encoding (files and folders names) is utf-8 of course (or, more exactly, as long as all your files and folders names are interpretable as valid utf-8). It won't do much for the file's content, of course.
- `codecs.open(file, "rb", encoding="utf8")` : this only makes sense if your file's content is actually some utf-8-encoded text, and obviously you are reading just any kind of binary data so it's not a surprise if you get spurious encoding errors.
- `buf.encode("ISO-8859-1")` : is just plain useless, `hashlib.sha1()` works fine with utf-8.

To make a long story short: **none** of your "fixes" makes sense.

To go back to the root of your problem:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file
>   It caused because not all the files name in english

I really think you assume too much here - if you get a non-ascii (not "non english") filename from browsing your filesystem then your filesystem **should** support this non-ascii encoding (well it's Windows so there might be some pecular things going on here but I can tell you I **never** had such a problem on Linux nor MacOS). At worst, if you're positive your "non english" (non-ascii really) filenames are utf8, you can try with **only** the `file = file.decode('utf-8')` to see if it works better but that's still [programming by accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_by_permutation).

Actually since you didn't post the effective traceback (with the full file name), it's hard to tell what really goes wrong with your original code, so your best bet is certainly to switch back to your first implementation and carefully read the full traceback. You can then use either the interactive Python shell or [the step debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to further inspect the problem.

Oh and yes: I assume you're using Python 2.x - Python 3 handles encoding a bit differently.

Comment: just found my problem

Comment: in the getallfiles was the problem 
i hed a file that have ～ in it name and it make it into a ~
and it not the same
btw how i edit a comment?

Answer (score 0):

so after i read what all of you write i understend my probem and really fix the code this time and it work fine
(found another problem with the dictionary that i didnt notice)
the working code:

```
import hashlib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os


def getallfolders(dir):
    folders = [d for d in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, d))]
    return folders


def getallfiles(dir):
    folders = [f for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir, f))]
    return folders


def filehash(file):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    hasher = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file, "rb") as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    return hasher.hexdigest()


def double_files(dir):
    print dir
    mil = {}
    folders = getallfolders(dir)
    for folder in folders:
        newmil = double_files(dir + folder + "\\")
        for i in newmil:
            if i in mil.keys():
                mil[i] = mil[i] + newmil[i]
            else:
                mil[i] = newmil[i]
    files = getallfiles(dir)
    for file in files:
        fhash = filehash(dir + file)
        if fhash in mil.keys():
            mil[fhash] = mil[fhash] + [dir + file]
        else:
            mil[fhash] = [dir + file]
    return mil


mil = double_files(u"E:\\not organised\\")
f = open('double_files.txt', 'w')
for i in mil:
    if len(mil[i]) > 1:
        for y in mil[i]:
            f.write(y.encode('utf8')+"\n")
        f.write("\n\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. Just a couple hints wrt/ how you use dicts: 1/ `dict.keys()` is a `list` so `x in mydict.keys()` is o(n). You'd better do a direct lookup, ie `x in mydict`, which is o(1). 2/ for your use case, a `collections.defaultdict` would just avoid any key lookup anyway ;)